# Is there a Python lib to calculate HTER?

Tags: computational-linguistics, machine-translation, python

Is there a Python lib that calculates HTER - Human-targeted Translation Error Rate?

Ideally it would expose a function that takes as parameters 1) at least one golden translation and 2) the translation in question.

Comment: (I did find https://github.com/wilkeraziz/PET/blob/master/scripts/hter.py, which calls Java.)

Comment: For details on HTER, read http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=193.

Comment: It would be good to add your comment as an answer, even though it's your own question :)